# PHP class not storing reference

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

How do I pass a reference to an object constructor, and allow that object to update that reference?

```
class A{
    private $data;
    function __construct(&$d){
        $this->data = $d;
    }
    function addData(){
        $this->data["extra"]="stuff";
    }
}

// Somewhere else
$arr = array("seed"=>"data");
$obj = new A($arr);
$obj->addData();

// I want $arr to contain ["seed"=>"data", "extra"=>"stuff"]
// Instead it only contains ["seed"=>"data"]
```

Comment: see examples here http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php and here http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: I wouldn't advice using this pattern; it makes your code unpredictable and hard to understand.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must store it everywhere as a reference.

```
function __construct (&$d) {
    $this->data = &$d; // the & here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to tell PHP to assign a reference also to the private member `data` like this:

```
$this->data = &$d;
```

Depending on the context, you may not want to use references to external arrays, and it might be better to have that array inside an object that handles it.

Aslo notice that the constructor is called `__construct` not `__construction`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I accepted the first correct one submitted.

Answer (score 1):

This would do what you are asking for:

```
class Test {

    private $storage;

    public function __construct(array &$storage)
    {
        $this->storage = &$storage;
    }

    public function fn()
    {
        $this->storage[0] *= 10;
    }
}

$storage = [1];

$a = new Test($storage);
$b = new Test($storage);

$a->fn();
print_r($a); // $storage[0] is 10
print_r($b); // $storage[0] is 10

$b->fn();
print_r($a); // $storage[0] is 100
print_r($b); // $storage[0] is 100
```

#### Alternative 1

Instead of using an array, you can also use an [`ArrayObject`](http://php.net/ArrayObject), [`ArrayIterator`](http://php.net/ArrayIterator) or [`SplFixedArray`](http://php.net/SplFixedArray). Since those are objects, they will be passed by reference. All of these implement [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/ArrayAccess) so you can access them via square brackets, e.g.

```
$arrayObject = new ArrayObject;
$arrayObject['foo'] = 'bar';
echo $arrayObject['foo']; // prints 'bar'
```

#### Alternative 2

Instead of using a generic type, use a dedicated type. Find out what you are storing in that array. Is it a `Config`? A `Registry`? A `UnitOfWork`? Find out what it really is. Then make it an object and give it an API reflecting the responsibilities. Then inject that object and access it through that API.

See this paper by [Martin Fowler to some guidance on When To Make A Type](http://martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/whenType.pdf)