# PHP how do I store and reuse a reference in object?

Tags: php, oop, reference

I have `object A` which has an array called `$storage`.

I want `object B` to use `object A`'s storage so I want to pass reference to `object A`'s storage as a parameter to `object B`'s constructor.

How can I save this reference and access it in `object B`?

In pseudo code:

```
class B {
    // What should I define here that can store the reference to object A storage?

    function __constructor (&$storage_on_a) {
        // What do I do here to keep the reference?
    }

    function use() {
        // How do I access to storage here using the reference ?
    }

}
```

Edit:

I dont want to pass A to B - this will be very bad programming as it will make B dependent on A. I want to pass a reference to an array which is much more isolated. (in this case the array is a property of A).  I need it by reference because I want data added by B to this array to be reflected on A so that when A decides to save its array the data will be saved.

Comment: Found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842510/php-class-not-storing-reference

@gordon Thanks for trying to help.